# Editable text not working in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

Using angular js on click of text, text should be editable. Currently not working. [Used this library](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/). Following code is in view page.

JS:

```js
var app = angular.module('virVenturesAPP', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','720kb.datepicker','xeditable']);//'720kb.datepicker'
var site_url = 'http://localhost/vv/';

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});
```

HTML:

```html
<table id="table_id" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" ng-show="numberLoad">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>RRD Track No</th>
            <th>Order Primary Key</th>
            <th>Order Id</th>
            <th>Mapped Date</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr dir-paginate="rrd in getRrdList |  itemsPerPage:rrdinfo.itemsPerPage" current-page="rrdinfo.currentPage" total-items="total_count">
            <td>{{rrd.id}}</td>
            <td>{{rrd.rrd_track_no}}</td>
            <td >{{rrd.ord_primary_key}}</td>
            <!-- <td editable-text="rrd.order_id" ng-if="rrd.order_id==='' "> <p contenteditable="true"> enter order</p></td>-->
            <td ng-if="rrd.order_id==='' ">  <a data-title="Enter username" editable-text="rrd.order_id" data-pk="1" data-type="text" id="usernameaa" href="#" class="editable editable-click edit_text" data-original-title="" title="">enter order id</a></td>
            <td ng-if="rrd.order_id!=='' ">{{rrd.order_id}}</td>
            <td>{{rrd.mapped_date}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: any error you are getting in console?

Comment: error in anguler.min.js line no 65

Comment: can you paste the complete error in question?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following code:

1. ng-show="numberLoad" line 2
2. ng-if="rrd.order_id==='' " line 18
3. ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','720kb.datepicker'] I think this line of code is the real problem

and it works:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/xdyh40dy/)

try to investigate better

```
   <div ng-app="virVenturesAPP" ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <table id="table_id" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>RRD Track No</th>
                        <th>Order Primary Key</th>
                        <th>Order Id</th>
                        <th>Mapped Date</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr dir-paginate="rrd in getRrdList |  itemsPerPage:rrdinfo.itemsPerPage" current-page="rrdinfo.currentPage" total-items="total_count">
                        <td>{{rrd.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{rrd.rrd_track_no}}</td>
                        <td >{{rrd.ord_primary_key}}</td>
                        <!-- <td editable-text="rrd.order_id" ng-if="rrd.order_id==='' "> <p contenteditable="true"> enter order</p></td>-->
                        <td >  <a data-title="Enter username" editable-text="rrd.order_id" data-pk="1" data-type="text" id="usernameaa" href="#" class="editable editable-click edit_text" data-original-title="" title="">enter order id</a></td>
                        <td ng-if="rrd.order_id!=='' ">{{rrd.order_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{rrd.mapped_date}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
 </div>
```

//script

```
var app = angular.module('virVenturesAPP', ['xeditable']);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';

});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.rrd = {
    order_id: 'awesome user'
  };
});
```